# Why do HDHPs have a maximum out of pocket?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, hsa, hdhp

I understand minimum deductibles (to ensure HSAs are only used with cheaper plans) but why the maximum out of pocket? It is worth noting it is different form the general maximum out of pocket of qualifying insurances as determined by ACA.

Comment: If there were no maximum out of pocket on the plan then it would certainly be less attractive to me as a consumer. I buy HDHP as catastrophic insurance. If I had no upper limit on my liability then I would likely choose a different plan.